# about Textbox Focus's Border color . C# Xaml Windows Phone8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, visual-studio-2015

Now I'm making a Editor.
When Textbox is Focused, blue border line appears

like this (left and right's Blue lines).

[image]

But I don't need this Blue (Focus) lines. So, I want to erase these lines.
And I don't know how to erase.

Now my xaml code is this.

```
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" 
             Background="White"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center"
             VerticalAlignment="Center"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Width="360"
             Height="200"
             Text="TextBox" />
```

These can be changed by xaml code ?

Comment: Will `BorderThickness="0"` help?

Comment: Glad it help. I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem want to clear that border completely. To do so add `BorderThickness="0"` to your XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" 
         Background="White"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Width="360"
         Height="200"
         BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
         Text="TextBox" />
```